# How do I write a java pattern in this format: filepath (int, int) (int,int)?

Tags: java, regex

For example

```
c:\55.bmp  (3,4) (45,7)
```

I want to get the filepath which is `c:\55.bmp` and the numbers 3, 4, 45 and 7.

Comment: are you asking for a reg ex pattern for c:\55.bmp (3,4) (45,7) or are you just asking how to get a file name from a file path ?

Comment: asking for a regex used in java to get the path of the file and those 4 numbers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`([A-z]:\\[^\s]*)\s\((\d*),(\d*)\)\s\((\d*),(\d*)\)`

This pattern will match "c:\55.bmp (3,4) (45,7)" with subgroups:

```
$1 = C:\55.bmp
$2 = 3
$3 = 4
$4 = 45
$5 = 7
```

Comment: Sure. Just remember this is dependent upon the format of "filepath_(#,#)_(#,#)" whereas "_" denotes a required space.

Comment: Thank you so much! but it seems not work with java pattern    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([A-z]:\\[^\s]*)\s\((\d*),(\d*)\)\s\((\d*),(\d*)\)"); doesn't complie

Comment: I change it to "([A-z]:\\\\[^\\s]*)\\s\\((\\d*),(\\d*)\\)\\s\\((\\d*),(\\d*)\\)"  it seems compile, but I still need to test it. thank you!

Comment: Your back-slash match should be "\\\\"

Comment: "([A-z]:\\\\[^\\s]*)\\s\\((\\d*),(\\d*)\\)\\s\\((\\d*),(\\d*)\\)" that should compile in Java

Comment: Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are  \b  \t  \n  \f  \r  \"  \'  \\ )  I think I have to change the \ to \\

Comment: Well...the comment isn't allowing me to add certain back-slashes hahah. Just take my original regex and replace every single back-slash with 2, and every 2 back-slashes with 4

Comment: The reason you need to change the "\s" to a "\\s" is because String and Regexs use the same escape character. If you were reading the regex from a file, then jerluc's pattern would work. But because you want to put it in a string, you need to encode it according to Java's string syntax.

Comment: yes. I did. it works. actually  I'm trying to use the the patten to match the input from command line and get the file path and those 4 numbers. Tyring to use scanner but looking for examples. can you give me an example? Thank you

Comment: Also, the "[^\s]*" can also be written as "\S*", capital letters are the inverse matching class.

Comment: If you're trying to read from the command line, are you sure that all those parts are going to be in a single string? Typically they would come into your main methods as an array: { "c:\55.bmp" , "(3,4)" , "(45,7)" }

Comment: yes. single string. maybe i can use BufferedReader. thank you

Comment: @jerluc: Did you really mean to write `[A-z]`?  If you're trying to match uppercase and lowercase letters, you have to spell it out: `[A-Za-z]`.  `[A-z]` also matches the six punctuation characters whose code points lie between `Z` and `a`.